# Translating .bil files in batch mode with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, convert

I have some .bil files that I would like to convert into ASCII Gridded XYZ format files.

It seems to work well with the Raster>Translate tool of QGIS when I process one file at a time. But I would like to do it by batch. So I checked the batch box but got this error message:

Processing of the following files ended with error:

> > C:/Users/Fall Line Tower/Desktop/Bil To Be Processed/Only Bill/PRISM_tmax_stable_4kmD1_19810101_bil.bil
> >     ERROR 4: `C:/Users/Fall Line Tower/Desktop/Bil To Be Processed/Onli Bill/PRISM_tmax_stable_4kmD1_19810101_bil.bil' not recognised as a supported file format. 
> >     GDALOpen failed - 4

I have the same error message for each .bil file within my source directory.

Any idea where the problem comes from?

Does the batch mode take only one type of format?

Not the .bil?

I am using QGIS 2.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Last time I used bil files in GDAL it was the .hdr that was considered the image and not the bil. Perhaps this is the case.

Comment: Have you created .hdr files? If so, you can point the command to the .hdr files and not .bil files.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the data are stored in the .bil not the .hdr according to the size of the files and this description provided with the dataset: "This format contains raster data with floating-point numbers. It is the native output format of the PRISM Climate Model. Each BIL zipfile includes multiple components, with different file
extensions: .xml (metadata for this dataset); .bil (dataset), .hdr (header info required for most BIL uses); .prj, .aux.xml (grid statistics), and .stx (required by some software)."

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a path issue ? When you launch as a batch, the spaces in the path could be wrongly interpreted. If it works for the translate tool it is not likely to be a format issue

Comment: Thank you. I tried to simplify the path and I deleted the .aux.xml files from the source folder. The file by file convertion still works but when I launch it as a batch, here is the new error message I get for every file in the source folder, QGIS seems to have some problems to handle the .hdr and .xml:

Comment: Processing of the following files ended with error: 
>> C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/selection/file1.hdr
ERROR 3: Failed to read scanline 0. 
ERROR 1: C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/selection/file1.hdr, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0 
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 0, Y block offset 0 
>> C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/selection/file1.xml
ERROR 3: Failed to read scanline 2. 
ERROR 1: C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/selection/file1.xml, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 2 
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 0, Y block offset 2

Comment: Note that when I individually convert the .bil to for example a .tiff then batch convert these .tiff created into some .xyz, it works fine. However, when I try to batch convert the .bil to .tiff, I get the same error messages as when I try to go from .bil to .xyz. As a result, it seems like the problem is really about the conversion tool launched as a batch on .bil files.

Comment: have you tried using gdal_translate directly from the command line ?

Comment: Not really. I don't have any experience with using the command line. I don't know how to use gdal_translate as a batch for example. Any suggestion? Another path that I should explore is the r.out.xyz command I believe.

Comment: Don't be afraid of the command line, it's very useful. The tool documents online give examples of how they're used. BIL (Band Interleaved by Line) are just raw data - a very old format which supports only RLE compression but I've never seen it applied. If you know the data type, cell size and origin you can read it as straight binary... done that before! You would need some python/c/VB skill though.

Comment: When you use the translate tool from QGIS the command line is shown in the bottom window. I was unable to get it to create gridded XYZ though without editing the command line. The batch translate fails because of the two-part file structure of the bil with header and data having the same base name. This is a problem in QGIS, not in GDAL_Translate which it calls: calling translate once for each part. The only way to do it in QGIS is to write your own add-in. If you want to know how to do it in command I'm happy to offer assistance.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I would love to learn how to write my own add-in. Do you have any tutorial to recommend?

Comment: Also, I have noticed that the batch conversion from .tiff to .xyz that I mentioned above doesn't work well. Indeed, it creates .xyz files but with characters encoding I don't recognize (string of characters like À33cÀ33cÀÂeÀ…kÀ33sÀáztÀ). As a result I can't for example use the data in Excel which is my final goal (I have tried to open the files selecting UTF-7 or 8, no success).  It's a little frustrating because I believe I could get my data in a .tiff instead of a .bil. So I thought I was close to find a solution.

Comment: @Bap - I had a similar problem today and solved with the help of this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22791/how-to-export-a-raster-layer-for-external-processing The answer works with the command line and on Ubuntu. So you would have to figure out how it works on windows but I guess trying the command line is easier than writing an add-in.

Answer (score 2):

1. locate gdal_translate.exe on your disk (e.g. C:\programs\qgis\bin\ )
2. write this Python code and launch it:

   ```
   import glob, subprocess

   pathbin = your_path_to_gdal
   pathfiles = your_path_to_files
   myfiles = glob.glob(pathfiles + "*.bil") #list of all bil files 
   for file in myfiles:
       subprocess.call([pathbin + "gdal_translate.exe", "-of", "XYZ", file, file[:-4] + ".csv"])
   ```

or you can also launch it from the dos command prompt

```
for /f %a IN ('dir /b /s "Disk:\Your\Directory\Name\*.bil"') do call "Disk:\Your\path\to_gdalbin\gdal_translate.exe" -of XYZ "%a" "%~dpna.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

To supplement this thread, apart from using the Command Line to specify the advanced parameter setting in Translate (Convert Format), one other option is the QGIS Processing Modeler. Simply customize the Translate (Convert Format) tool with the data type conversion (e.g. float to uint16), save the model, and run it as a batch process (by right-clicking it).