# What is the meaning of -32768 in gdaldem color config?

Tags: nodata, gdaldem

I found a gdaldem color config:

```
3500 140 140 140
2500 209 209 209
1500 225 225 225
700 245 245 245
0 252 252 252
-32768 213 232 237 <=== What mean -32768
```

Comment: Wild guess: it probably means *NoData*.

Comment: gdaldem documentation say: "The elevation value can be any floating point value, or the nv keyword for the nodata value" But what is the usage of "nodata value" and where is written -32768 ==> nodata value

Comment: Yup, means `nodata`. If you want to redefine it, there are a number of posts here in GIS:SE such as [How to redefine the nodata value into zero in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/how-to-redefine-the-nodata-value-into-zero-in-qgis). @Gerd, you should provide a link to the documentation you got the quote from :)

Comment: documentation: http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html

Comment: "nodata value" mean: no high profile data accessible for this area > no generation of color-relief possible here. @Joseph It is correct?

Comment: @Gerd - My understanding is that `nodata` simply means that there is no data for the given area (i.e. [absence of data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/nodata-in-raster-datasets.htm)). Usually `nodata` values are expressed with ridiculous numbers such as `-32768` or `-9999` etc. So yes, I believe you are correct although I'm not an expert so hopefully others can advise =)

Answer (score 3):

```
-32768  213 232 237
```

means: Take color "rgb 213 232 237" if in any area are no data for gdaldem color-relief rendering.

Remark: This question was result of my using NASA SRMT data from

http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Eurasia/*.

This SRMT data contain a lot of NODATA areas!

Better download NASA SRMT data from

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp

This data are complete. No NODATA areas!