# How to replace the Nan or nodata values into 0?

Tags: qgis, raster, nodata

I have a raster in .img format and i would trasform some values (Nan) into 0 with QGIS 2.14.3 (Windows). 
I've tried different ways but I didn't have results:
1- with raster --> conversion --> conversion format 
2- operations with raster calculator (to replace non-zero values).
With this operations, Nan values have been replaced by Nodata. After I have repeated the same operations but no data values haven't been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

you can try SextanteToolbox in QGIS:

Work Flow:

> Analysis --> Sextante toolbox --> SAGA --> Grid Tools --> Reclassify Grid Values

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/how-to-redefine-the-nodata-value-into-zero-in-qgis is a similar kind of question and discussion.