# Filling nodata in a DEM using values from another DEM (in QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, raster-calculator

I have a 50cm Digital Terrain Model (tiff) with some nodata values. Instead of interpolating them, I would like to fill them in with values from a lower resolution (1m) DTM of the same area. I think this can be achieved using the raster calculator, but can't for the life of me work it out.

I'm working in QGIS 2.18.

Comment: The linked question does not appear to be a dupe of this. It asks about converting 0 to NoData. This question asks how to replace NoData values with values from a different raster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Change "nodata" value of your base (50cm DTM) raster to some unused value (for example `0` or `-9999`) with gdal_translate `Raster --> Conversion --> Translate (Convert format)`. See mentioned question [Redefining nodata value into zero in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/redefining-nodata-value-into-zero-in-qgis).
2. Then in raster calculator use this expression (for nodata value `0`):

   ```
   ("base@1"=0)*"filler@1"+("base@1"!=0)*"base@1"
   ```

   This will go through rasters and do: if pixel value in `base` raster is `0` take value from `filler` raster, if pixel value in `base` raster is not `0` keep value (exactly take value from `base` raster again)