# Replacing nodata values by a constant using GDAL CLI tools

Tags: gdal, nodata

I have a raster DEM file containing 1 band: `f='DEM.tif'`
It has some NODATA values which I want to replace by a true, actual constant value (i.e. no more nodata stuff), let's say, zero.

Here are all the things I've tested:

1. [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html); not working:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 ${f} ${f%.*}_cleaned.tif
```

well... it actually replaces the nodata value of 3.399999^38 to a nodata value of 0, but it doesn't replace it by a *true* 0 (which would be an actual zero value, no a nodata value).

2. I also tried the accepted answer here using [`gdalbuildvrt`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html): [Redefining nodata value into zero in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/redefining-nodata-value-into-zero-in-qgis) but with no success. Nodata values still show as ... well, nodata values.
3. Also, there is the [`gdal_fillnodata`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_fillnodata.html) tool, which seemed promising: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_fillnodata.html but it actually interpolates values from the closest borders, which doesn't make sense in my case.
4. Finally, [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) was my last candidate, but it is not working better:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata 3.39999995214436425e+38 -dstnodata 0 ${f} ${f%.*}_cleaned.tif
```

because, here again, it replaces the nodata value by another nodata value, which is *not* what I would like to achieve.

I've done that successfully in no time with [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) using the "Fill NoData cells" on my local machine as a test, but I must work on my full dataset on a headless server, without QGIS installed.

So, do you know how to fill nodata values by a constant using any of the GDAL CLI (bash) based tools?  I hope I simply missed something obvious...

#### Edits

5. *Removed as it was a malformed version of @user2856's working answer.*
6. I forgot to mention this when I wrote the post, but I also tried @Mike T's first part of his answer:

```
gdal_edit.py -unsetnodata ${f}
```

(**Disclaimer**: this is a non reversible operation as it's actually working 'inplace', so backup your raster before running this command!)

Here, on the contrary, `gdalinfo` doesn't report NoData anymore. But do not rejoice too quickly, as a loading into QGIS shows:

[image: QGIS indentify results]

The second part of Mike T's answer:

```
gdal_calc.py -A ${f}.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="numpy.where(A>=3e34, 0, A)"
```

is actually giving a `result.tif` raster with:

```
gdalinfo result.tif | grep No
  NoData Value=3.40282346600000016e+38
```

That's funny? Probably some weird numerical issue under the hood.
But the most funny part is that if I first run `gdal_edit.py -unsetnodata`
and then the latter `gdal_calc.py` command, the resulting raster has so nodata again (heck, where do these actually come from?)!

---

General info on my setup just in case:

```
# gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.3.0dev-33cf0e31a992be112b3091f012368d15605ed51d, released 2021/03/17
```

from `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest` Docker image available at https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One (slightly hacky) way of doing it is to use an intermediate VRT with the `gdalbuildvrt` command and specifying a new NoData value with the `srcnodata` and `vrtnodata` arguments. This does actually change the underlying values.

First, get your actual nodata value from `gdalinfo`:

```sh
$ gdalinfo input.tif | grep No
NoData Value=3.39999995214436425e+38
```

Assign it to a bash variable: `na=3.39999995214436425e+38`

Or if you have [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed (in ubuntu/debian based Linux distros `sudo apt install jq`):

```sh
na=$(gdalinfo input.tif -json | jq '.bands[0].noDataValue')
```

And use it in the following examples:

```sh
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata ${na} -vrtnodata 0 output.vrt input.tif
```

However, it also sets those values to NoData in the output, so you need to specify a different value to be considered as NoData when converting to your final GeoTIFF.

```sh
gdal_translate -a_nodata ${na} output.vrt output.tif  # original 3.39999995214436425e+38 values from input.tif are now 0
```

Chaining it together with a pipe so you don't need to clean up any intermediate VRT files:

```sh
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata ${na} -vrtnodata 0 /vsistdout/ input.tif | gdal_translate -a_nodata -9999 /vsistdin/ output.tif
```

Comment: When I do run your two first commands (or the one-line one), `gdalinfo` says there still are some `NoData Value=-9999` and when I open the resulting raster in QGIS, there still are white areas representing the nodata values (which apparently are interpreted as `3.3999999521444e+38` vs `-9999` with gdalinfo (strange).

Comment: Did you replace "-9999" with your *actual* NoData value in the first (`gdalbuildvrt`) command? i.e something like `gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 3.3999999521444e+38  -vrtnodata 0 /vsistdout/ input.tif | gdal_translate -a_nodata -9999 /vsistdin/ output.tif`

Comment: Doh! Nope, sorry. I will try it again and update the OP in consequence. But I always fear some glitches when copy-pasting such large numerical values, especially if they got rounded at some point. Is it safe to copy the value from the output of `gdalinfo` for example?

Comment: I made a test tif with a nodata value = 3.3999999521444e+38 and the above command worked.   Use `gdalinfo -json input.tif` to get an unrounded value. Should look something like `"noDataValue":339999995214440013906259394729726705664.0`

Comment: Okay, it seems to work. I prefixed your answer with an explanation on how to extract the actual `3.39999995214436425e+38` value so that I can accept it. Many thanks again.

Comment: I've added an edit to show how to grab NoData value using `jq`, e.g.  `na=$(gdalinfo input.tif -json | jq '.bands[0].noDataValue')`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some untested ideas:

1. Use [`gdal_edit.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html) to remove the NoData metadata from the file. This is an in-place edit, so make sure you have a back-up, or use a copy of the original file. E.g.:

```bash
   gdal_edit.py -unsetnodata file.tif
```

2. Use [`gdal_calc.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html) to modify the values, by replacing one value with another. Numpy's [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function does this. For example to replace a previous nodata 3.399999e+38 with 1.1:

```bash
   gdal_calc.py -A file.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="numpy.where(A>=3e38, 1.1, A)"
```

The condition `A>=3e38` will avoid floating point issues while trying to pick exact values.

Comment: Thanks. I actually also tested `gdal_edit.py` with this `-unsetnodata` option (it seemed promising) but without any success. It simply "removes" the information that these values are representing nodata but then, if I load it in QGIS, it always shows white areas with values around 3.4^38 which can definitely no be interpreted as actual altitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following which works for me:

1. replace your_original_nodata_value (e.g. 0) with a_new_nodata_value (e.g., -9999):

gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=output.tif --calc='(A==0)*(-9999)+(A!=0)*A'

2. set the new_nodata_value as nodata:

gdal_translate -a_nodata -9999 output.tif output_2.tif

Then output_2.tif should be your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I build a small Python function depending on [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that may be helpful for people having access to Python. But I consider this only as a *quick'n'dirty* alternative:

```py
import os, glob, rasterio

folder = '/path/to/your/rasters/'
files_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder,'*.tif'))

def replace_nodata_by(input_file, replacement_value=0):
    epsg = 31983
    outfile = input_file.split('.')[0]+'_fixed.tif'
    with rasterio.open(input_file, mode='r', driver='GTiff',
                       count=None, crs='EPSG:'+str(epsg), transform=None,
                       dtype='float32', nodata=None) as source_dataset:
        data_array = source_dataset.read()
        data_array[data_array > 1e5] = replacement_value # kick out nodata values
        # This is a bonus step in my case to fill under ocean level's 
        # values with zeros as well:
        data_array[data_array < 0] = replacement_value
        output_metadata = source_dataset.meta
   
    output_metadata.update({"driver": "GTiff", "nodata": -9999})
    with rasterio.open(outfile, "w", **output_metadata) as destination_dataset:
        destination_dataset.write(data_array.astype(rasterio.float32))
    
    return True
        
for file in files_list:
    print(f"Processing {file}...")
    replace_nodata_by(file, replacement_value=0)
```

`gdalinfo` will tell there still is a nodata value of `-9999` now, but if you carefully look at the code, I've set up this new `-9999` value just to be able to differentiate it from the original nodata value in case of any kind of failure/bug. But normally, there will be no such values in the output raster files.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use gdal_calc and [numpy.nan_to_num](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```bsh
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=output.tif \
    --calc="numpy.nan_to_num(A)"
```

Variations on this should let you specify the value to replace NaNs:

```bsh
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=output.tif \
    --calc="numpy.nan_to_num(A, nan=123)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this question, and went back to the documentation of `gdal_calc.py` here: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html

If you are using version 3.3 or newer, you can combine the following to get the desired results:

- use `numpy.where` to replace the old NoDataValue with new value
- option `--hideNoData` to ignore the input band NoDataValue
- option `--NoDataValue='none'` will result in output with no NoDataValue

Your command would look like this:

```
gdal_calc.py -A DEM.tif --calc="numpy.where(A>=3e38, 0, A)" \
  --outfile DEM_clean.tif --hideNoData --NoDataValue='none'
```