# Removing no data and saving raster file using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, nodata

I want to remove the no data values from my raster and save the resulting file. Currently, I am using the method shown below to save the raster without no data values.

[image]

The issue is that I have to save more than 100 raster files after removing no data values, which range from 30000 to 33000.

Is there any code or method to automatically do this?

Comment: Do you have those Rasters directly in QGIS or somewhere in a folder? Should output rasters be placed in the same folder as the input?

Comment: You can try with the Raster Calculator and after `QgsRasterFileWriter` https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Raster/QgsRasterFileWriter.html. Otherwise check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350471/99589

Comment: @Taras I have them in a single folder. It is okay if the output rasters are placed in the same folder with a new name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *Graphical Modeler* in QGIS to create a small Python-script.

In your case you would set a Raster layer as say *input_raster* and use that as the input for *r.null* to set certain values to NULL and write the new raster into an output file.

As with all these scripts you can either run this for each file singularly or as a batch process. Since you will still have to fill in some things like input and output filenames I am not sure, how much time this effectively saves in the end, but it should make the process somewhat faster.