# Multiply two rasters with condition

Tags: qgis, raster, nodata, conditional

I have two rasters that I want to multiply in QGIS with raster calculator, but they both have also cells with 'no data'.

If I multiply simply raster1 by raster2, the result of the multiplication between a number and a 'no data' cell is 'no data'.

Instead, I would like to get an output raster where the result of the multiplication between a number and a 'no data cell' is the number.

How can I do that? maybe with a 'ifelse' condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GRASS GIS module `r.mapcalc` allows to build an `if(...)` expression in order to ignore nodata pixels. The format (check the [r.mapcalc manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.mapcalc.html)) is: `if(condition, result if true, result if false)`.

Here's a sample code:

```
r.mapcalc "R_result = if(isnull(R1), R2, if(isnull(R2, R1, R1 * R2)))"
```

Note that if both rasters are nodata, the result will be nodata.

Comment: Thank you, with just a minor correction: if(isnull(R1), R2, if(isnull(R2), R1, R1 * R2)). The module name is now r.mapcalc.simple

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try just changing the nodata value to 1?
About redefined nodata value see [there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/redefining-nodata-value-into-zero-in-qgis)

Comment: Thank you but I can't since one of the two rasters has already some values equal to 1, so it would add additional 1 that are not true in the final raster.